# Arangodb Sharding Issue

Tags: sharding, arangodb

I am using Arangodb cluster in two hosts (say host 'A' and host 'B'). I made both of them as coordinator and DBServer . Lets say my configurations are:
Host A: IP1 port 8530 (coordinator port 8531)
Host B: IP2 port 8530 (coordinator port 8531)
Now i have 2 apps listening to host 'A' and host 'B' respectively (on port 8531). Suppose Host 'A' coordinator goes down then app 'A' stops listening while app 'B' is working fine.
How can i make app 'A' to listen to Host 'B' if Host 'A' is down and vice versa?

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like HAproxy (or any other HTTP load balancer in soft- or hardware). ArangoDB speaks "standard" HTTP so you can use TCP or HTTP load-balancers.

Depending on your network topology you can install HAproxy on each client or setup a central HAproxy.